# SKSpriteNode collision with edge wall

Tags: ios, swift

I've got some object (SKSpriteNode) that are going from top to down and when they are on the end of bottom screen, they disappear.
The problem is that sometimes that objects go out of screen (left or right edge) and I should add some "walls" that block this.
I have no idea how do it.

Struct of Physics:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None      : UInt32 = 0
    static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let PhysicsSweet: UInt32 = 0b1
}
```

Code to spawn object:

```
    let randomSweetPosition = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(400))+300)
    let sweet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cake0")
    sweet.xScale = 0.4
    sweet.yScale = 0.4
    sweet.position = CGPoint(x : randomSweetPosition, y : 768)
    self.addChild(sweet)

    sweet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sweet.size.height/2)
    sweet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    sweet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PhysicsSweet
    sweet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
```